# Arma 3 - Playing Dynamic Universal War System on a dedicated server

Tags: mods, server-administration, arma-3

I am trying to setup Dynamic Universal War System on my dedicated server. Originally, this mod (it is in fact a mission file with lots of other files like sqf, hpp, ext, etc) is not made to work on dedicated server but only on listen servers. this is because the host player has to setup different variables in a GUID created by the mod. On a dedicated server, the mod does not have anybody to ask those variables so it is impossible to create a game.

One of my theories to make it work is to create the game locally on my computer then transfer the save files to the server and continue the game there. For that, I've copied the mission files in the MPMission folder of my Arma 3 directory to make it as similar as possible to the server environnement. The problem is that I am unable to locate the save files of that mission on my computer and i do not know where I need to copy those save files on the server.

My second option would be to edit the main .pbo and the INIT file so the varaibles asked at the beginning of the games are already filled and it generates the missions from that. The problem is that I do not know which part of the file I need to edit to make it work.

**TL;DR**
How can I hack my way into setting up Dynamic Universal War System on a dedicated server by copying the save files created on my computer to the server and/or how do I change the variables so the game generates the mission from those variables without the need of the GUI.